# How to calculate normal vector along an axis?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, coordinate-systems

I am struggling to understand how to calculate the normal vector $(x,y,z)$ along the axis for a given object. I have selected the center of one object $A$ to be a base point so the $(x,y,z)$ coordinate of this object is $(0,0,0)$.

I then measure the center of an object $B$ that is place on the right of this object and sits below it and the coordinate is $(0.44,0.08, -0.33)$.

How do I now calculate the norm vector for object $A$ and $B$?
the measurement means that the object is $44$ cm away from the base point to the right $(x)$ , is $8$ cm in front of the base point $(y)$ and $33$ cm downwards $(z)$.

Comment: Usually, a normal vector refers to a vector that is perpendicular to a surface (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html) and therefore has nothing to do with **where** the geometry is located. Does it have a different meaning in this case?

Comment: Thanks for the link. this is what the normal vector is referring to as per the diagram shown in the link. so how do i define this surface and get the normal vector for the object?

Comment: It would depend on how you have created the surface. Are you using some software for it?

Comment: no, measurements taken by hand and sketching on paper.

Comment: Well, if all you have is a manual drawing, then a manual drawing is the best that you can do for the normal vector, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: By the way, why do you need to compute the normal vector? Will you use the result in some other computation?

Comment: yes it will make sense to do it manually too. the information will be used for other computation as well.